# Sympy: C code from logical expression

Tags: python, code-generation, sympy

From a sympy logical expression, I would like to get the equivalent C code. First off, I noticed that you cannot use the native logical operators like `and` and `or` because sympy somehow strips them off. Fair enough, there's [`&` and friends](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/logic.html). I tried

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.utilities.codegen import codegen

x = Symbol('x')
is_valid = Symbol('is_valid')

# f = x > 0 and is_valid  # TypeError: cannot determine truth value of
f = (x > 0) & is_valid  # And(is_valid, x > 0)

# TypeError: The first argument must be a sympy expression.
[(c_name, c_code), (h_name, c_header)] = codegen(("f", f), "C")
```

but for some reason, I'm getting

> TypeError: The first argument must be a sympy expression.

Any hints?

Comment: Sympy doesn't strip `and` and `or` off. Those operators are ”hard coded” in Python and can't be overloaded by types, so Python tries to execute them and that fails or doesn't yield the result you want.

Comment: @Nico - I would like to delete my answer. Could you please un-mark it as being correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is based on a hard-coded isinstance check. If it is removed, I get

```
#include "f.h"
#include <math.h>

double f(double is_valid, double x) {

   double f_result;
   f_result = is_valid && x > 0;
   return f_result;

}
```

Note however that this is still probably not what you want, since `is_valid` is set as a double, and you probably want it to be an int (or C99 bool).

My suggestion: use `ccode` on your expression directly, and write the function wrapper manually. You could also use [pycodeexport](https://github.com/bjodah/pycodeexport) if you need something more scalable.

Comment: I've tried deleting (SO won't let me -_-) my answer since your answer is more correct :). I see you're the lead dev on sympy. Any plans on this?

Comment: @RuHasha yep, there are plans for improving the code generation in sympy.